# Enable Right-Click on Mac OS X 10.7.5 by default

Tags: macos, mac, macbook-pro

Is there a way to enable mouse right clicking on Macs? I did some searching but I don't have a mouse and keyboard option together. I have a track pad but I can't find any right click options.

This is a mac book pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

I had enable the secondary click option and set it to the bottom right. Weird name for a right click...

Comment: "Right click" would be a weird name for something that might actually be Control-Click, or tapping the bottom left corner of the trackpad, or...

Answer (score 1):

Enabling a Literal Right-Click OS X:

- Open System Preferences
- Click on Trackpad
- Under the ‘One Finger’ section, select the checkbox next to “Secondary Click” and select “Bottom Right Corner”
- Adjust the standard Mac OS X secondary click behavior with a two fingered click as you see fit

[image]

Source: [OSXDaily](http://osxdaily.com/2011/05/24/enable-right-click-mac/)

Comment: What if yours does not look anything like that?